# Where is home directory in GCP app engine standard environment?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, home-directory

I have distributed the django web page to the app engine of the gcp standard environment, and now I want to distribute it including the marvinJS of chemaxon.

In order to use that app, you need to put the license in that path.

```
(home directory)/.chemaxon
```

However, I can't find the home directory of the distributed standard environment app engine.

Also, if you find it, how should you move the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Engine standard is a packaged solution. You submit your code, it is compiled (if required) and packaged in a container (with Buildpack). You don't manage the environment, the home directory, the users,....

So, try to add your file in the root path of your code. You won't be able to put the file higher in the dir path..